# Apply the Abel summation formula to $\sum_{i=1}^k \operatorname{sinc} \bigl( \pi (x-i p) \bigr)$

Tags: integration, limits, summation, trigonometric-series, summation-method

As part of an exploration of the Abel Summation formula ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula)), I am looking at an impulse train $T$ made up of $k$ $\operatorname{sinc}$ pulses at intervals $p$ along the $x$ axis:

$$T(x):=\sum_{i=1}^k \operatorname{sinc} \bigl( \pi (x-i p) \bigr)$$

For example, setting $p=3$ and $k=5$ gives

[image]

I am seeking tips on how to apply Abel summation to $T$ - or an explanation of why it isn't possible.

The Wikipedia page linked above (under "Variations") gives a summation formula for the indexed sum of some function $\phi$ that is continuously differentiable on real $x \ge 1$. Define a partial sum $A$ by

$$A(t) = \sum_{0 \le n \le t}a_n$$

for a real number $t$ and a sequence of real numbers $a_n$. Set $a_0 = 0$ and $a_n = 1$ for all $n \ge 1$ so that $A(t) = \lfloor t \rfloor$. Then

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{1 \le n \le x} a_n \phi(n)  &=  \lfloor x \rfloor \phi(x) - \int_1^x \lfloor u \rfloor \phi'(u) \, du
\\&= x \phi(x) - \{x\}  \phi(x) - \int_1^x u \phi'(u) \, du + \int_1^x \{u\} \phi'(u) \, du
\end{aligned}$$

Here, $\{y \}$ indicates the fractional part of $y$. In order to evaluate the expressions containing the fractional part function, I use a 'proxy' in the form of an explicit formula for the sawtooth function with a limit taken to ensure that it evaluates to zero for integer values of the argument:

$$s(y) := \frac{1}{2} - \underset{\epsilon \to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\frac{\tan ^{-1}(\cot (\pi  (y + \epsilon)))}{\pi }$$

So far, so good. But then I hit a wall.

There are so many variables (plus a dummy variable!) knocking around that I am unsure how to define $\phi$ in a way that allows Abel summation to work. I am also losing track of which variations I have tried - although the main one was defining $\phi(i):=\operatorname{sinc} \bigl( \pi (x-i p) \bigr)$ and differentiating and integrating with respect to $I$ (using Mathematica). It didn't work.

So, could someone pleases suggest how I should proceed, or explain why it won't work?

Comment: According to my CAS (Mathematica) we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{sinc}(\pi(x-kp))=\frac{i\exp(-i\pi(p+x))}{2p\pi}\bigg(e^{2\pi ix}\Phi(e^{-ip\pi},1,1-x/p)-e^{2\pi i x}(e^{-ip\pi})^n\Phi(e^{-ip\pi},1,n+1-x/p)-e^{2ip\pi}\Phi(e^{ip\pi},1,1-x/p)+e^{2i p\pi}(e^{ip\pi})^n\Phi(e^{ip\pi},1,n+1-x/p)\bigg)$$
Where $\Phi$ is the Lerch transcendent. So uh, good luck.

Comment: Hi @K.defaoite, yes, the resulting expression would be ugly as a very ugly thing! But my question is, is it in fact possible...?

Comment: I mean maybe, but is it worthwhile?!

Comment: As an exercise in helping understand how to apply Abel summation in a situation with multiple variables? It seems interesting to me, hence wanting to know how It's possible or if It's possible, rather than wanting a full solution... I hope that makes sense! :-)